# Is there a secret area in Hollows 11?

Tags: the-end-is-nigh

I've pushed a few rocks in Hollows 11, altough nothing special happened. 
[image: game]

Is there any aditional step I should take to reveal a secret area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you leave the screen on the bottom right side, there is a room with a Mega Tumor. I don't know about more specials there. If you look up this room on different websites for tips, there isn't mentioned anything special about these rocks.

Comment: That's disappointing... (thank you again anyway, next time I just better ask you directly =P )